# zend framework zend_db: what does it provide to escape sql parameters

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-db

what does zend framework provides in order to escape user input into a query string ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See [Quoting Values and  Identifiers](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.db.adapter.html#zend.db.adapter.quoting). You can also use [Zend_Db_Select](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.db.select.html) when creating your query, which will automatically call quoteInto.